# Java: How can I test to see if there are matching sequential numbers?

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a raffle ticket program where multiple prizes can be earned depending on how the person's 6-digit ticket number matches with the 6-digit winning number.

One of prizes can be earned if 3 sequential numbers out of the winning number matches with 3 sequential numbers of the person's ticket.

Example: If the number on the ticket is 123456, it is a winner if the winning number has 123 in positions 1 – 3, 234 in positions 2 – 4, 345 in positions 3 – 5, or 456 in positions 4 – 6.

I was wanting to know how I would able to do this with the lottery numbers/tickets being ints?

Comment: by checking all current combo's with all winning combinations. EDIT: the solution proposed by @aelor is indeed easier.

Comment: by checking the index of the number in your original number

Comment: Can a single ticket win 2 prizes by matching positions 1-3 AND positions 2-4?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the test using modulo arithmetic to test 3 digits at a time, and repeatedly divide by 10 to test different sets of 3 digits:

```
static boolean match3(int ticket, int winner)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if((ticket % 1000) == (winner % 1000))
            return true;
        ticket /= 10; winner /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Numbers with less than 6 digits are assumed to have leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic to fulfill your need.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //This is containing all possible ascending combination
        String possibleComb = "0123456789"; 
        //This would be variable and will be part of your method argument
        String ticketNumber = "123456"; 

        //This loop is to get all 3 combination in only forward direction
        for(int i = 0; i < ticketNumber.length() - 1;){ 
            String tmpSubStr = ticketNumber.substring(i, i + 3);
            if(possibleComb.indexOf(tmpSubStr) == (Integer.parseInt(tmpSubStr) / 100)) {
                System.out.println("He is Lucky Customer of " + (i + 1) + "-" + (i + 3));
            }
            System.out.println();
            i = i + 3;
        }
    }
}
```